# Unix-like reference to parent and root Association?

Tags: associations, query

Is there a syntax or function to reference parent and root  when querying nested  Associations similar to Unix' ".." and "/", eg "cd ../../mydir". ?

Here's a typical application of the root construct. Given a nested dataset:

```
ds = <|  "study" -> <|   "all"  -> <|"n" -> 223.`, "Median" -> 18.5` |>|>, 
        "bySite" -> <|   "VASD" -> <|"n" -> 107.`, "Median" -> 20.40`|>, 
                         "UCSD" -> <|"n" -> 116.`, "Median" -> 16.5` |>|>, 
  "bySpeciality" -> <|"Primary" -> <|"n" -> 127.`, "Median" -> 17.8` |>, 
                    "Specialty" -> <|"n" -> 96.` , "Median" -> 19.5` |>|>|> // Dataset
```

[image]

(Dataset is only used here for formatting convenience)

using `ds["study","all","n"]` as denominator, the query is to convert all values of the instances "n" to ratios:

```
   ds[All, All, #/ds["study", "all", "n"] &]
```

[image]

But how can it be used in a query without reference to `ds`? For example, would like to use something like `RootAssociation`

```
ds // Query[All, All, {"n" -> (#/RootAssociation["study", "all", "n"] &)}]
```

`ParentAssociation` would work in a similar way

Comment: In general you'll be more likely to get responses if you use code that others can immediately evaluate, and simplify your examples as far as you can. The RightCompositions make the code harder to read and understand for someone who isn't familiar with it already.

Comment: @user6014, re the first point, I'll replace w/ a self-contained version. Re RightComposition - I think it makes code *easier* to read, it's just an infix version.

Comment: @user6014, I simplified the example to make it more readable.

Comment: What about `Function[RootAssociation,  RootAssociation//Query[All, All, {"n" -> (#/RootAssociation["study", "all", "n"] &)}] ]` isn't necessarily better but you can define queries separately.

Comment: @Kuba, I would consider that cheating, as you might as well write: `ds // Function[ds, 
 ds // Query[All, All, {"n" -> (#/ds["study", "all", "n"] &)}]]` - maybe a version using `UpValues`?

Comment: @alancalvitti sure, the point is you don't need to know the name of the dataset before.

Comment: @Kuba, good point, but needs to be user friendly - can you define it using `UpValues` for `rootAssociation` and also `parentAssociation`? If so will award.

Comment: @Kuba, also I'm writing a book where I'd like to use these functions, and will be happy to cite you.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to define it using `UpValues` because the RootAssociation could be buried quite deeply in the query. For this example I can make something work by injecting a replacement rule for RootAssociation into ``Dataset`OverrideMissing`` (which wraps the actual call that applies the converted query function to the association data). I think the approach is too flimsy for serious use though.

Comment: The code is ``SubValues[Dataset`OverrideMissing] =
 {HoldPattern[Dataset`OverrideMissing[f_][e_]] :> 
   Dataset`BlockMissingBehavior[(f /. RootAssociation :> e)[e]]}``

Comment: @alancalvitti I agree with Simon, I was trying to override `Query` but it is protected internally.