# How to get parent key in Query on Association/Dataset?

Tags: associations, query

Is there a general and terse method to obtain the parent key of the current "position" in a `Query` of an `Association`/`Dataset`?

Say I have the following `Association`.

```
assoc =
 <|"A" ->
    <|"a" -> <|"one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3|>,
      "b" -> <|"one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3|>|>,
   "B" ->
    <|"c" -> <|"four" -> 4, "five" -> 5, "six" -> 6|>,
      "d" -> <|"four" -> 4, "five" -> 5, "six" -> 6|>|>
 |>
```

It is easy to get a position's child keys with `KeyValueMap`.

```
Query[All, Association@KeyValueMap[#1 -> f[#1, Keys@#2] &]]@assoc
```

> ```
> <|"A" -> <|"a" -> f["a", {"one", "two", "three"}], 
>            "b" -> f["b", {"one", "two", "three"}]|>, 
>   "B" -> <|"c" -> f["c", {"four", "five", "six"}], 
>            "d" -> f["d", {"four", "five", "six"}]|>
> |>
> ```

However, to get the parent key a nesting of `KeyValueMap` is used.

```
Association@Query[
   KeyValueMap[
    Function[{parent, child},
     parent ->
      Association @@ KeyValueMap[#1 -> f[parent, #1] &]@child
     ]
    ]]@assoc
```

> ```
> <|"A" -> <|"a" -> f["A", "a"], "b" -> f["A", "b"]|>, 
>   "B" -> <|"c" -> f["B", "c"], "d" -> f["B", "d"]|>
> |>
> ```

And

```
Association@Query[
   KeyValueMap[
    Function[{parent, child},
     parent ->
      Association @@ KeyValueMap[f[parent, #1] -> #2 &]@child
     ]
    ]]@assoc
```

> ```
> <|"A" -> 
>    <|f["A", "a"] -> <|"one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3|>, 
>      f["A", "b"] -> <|"one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3|>|>, 
>   "B" -> 
>    <|f["B", "c"] -> <|"four" -> 4, "five" -> 5, "six" -> 6|>, 
>      f["B", "d"] -> <|"four" -> 4, "five" -> 5, "six" -> 6|>|>
> |>
> ```

This seems to be a lot of effort for what should be an easy task for a hierarchical structure.

Am I completely doing this wrong?  Is there built-in support for getting a position's parent key?

Comment: You could do things like this: `MapIndexed[f @@ Map[First, #2] &, assoc, {2}]`. But in general, since assocs are immutable, they don't store references to their parents (because they don't have parents, in a sense), so it should be expected that going "up" is harder than going "down".

Comment: @LeonidShifrin What about the case of `Dataset[assoc]`? Is there some way with that since it is an hierarchical object by design?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You may generate an actual query and look at it (``Dataset`CompileQuery``), perhaps things like `MapIndexed` would also just work there, but there isn't any built-in Dataset - level mechanism to reference parents, AFAIK.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I suppose `Map[Association@*Values, #, {1}] &@
 MapIndexed[f[Sequence @@ Map[First, #2]] -> #1 &, assoc, {2}]` for the second case. Still very verbose considering `Dataset` is a hierarchical object.

Comment: Yep, something like that. Re:verbose - I agree, the more transparent access to parent keys / positions could've been built-in. But again, immutability makes this a harder problem (while making many other things vastly simpler).

Comment: This question is a very similar, if not identical, to [Unix-like reference to parent and root Association?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131337/142).  No answer there yet either :(

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131337/unix-like-reference-to-parent-and-root-association .. I suggested this to WRI support, who replied it's a good idea. However, they are always backlogged.